# How to extract scene locations from a given text?

Tags: nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I am working on a task where I am supposed to find/extract details about scene locations. Consider following sentences:

1 - *Open on a small school classroom in south Italy*.

2 - *Cut to dawn breaking over a wheat field.*

In the first sentence, it should extract "school classroom" or "classroom". For the later one, it should extract "wheat field".

I was unable to find any resources related to this task. I would like to know:

- whether this is possible or not
- if yes, then how? Links to any paper/code will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Atleast try to show some of your efforts done by an example

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: I've used OpenNLP and StanfordNLP libraries for Java, they can detect locations in sentences. Python probably has its own libraries.

Comment: @Rachitkapadia I have no clue where to start with that's why I have posted this question here. I know how to extract geopolitical locations but this problem is different.

Comment: @MinorThreat What type of locations? As you can see it's not geo locations so I guess NER wouldn't work in this case. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @chrisz I was looking for a solution in Python. I think I shouldn't have done this because it's more about NLP than Python. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: AFAIR these libraries were able to deduce function of a noun in a sentence. Location is one of these functions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried visualizing what a parser can do? (Java: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/, Python: https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/)

Very much depending on the notes you have describing locations, maybe you can hack something together by detecting location prepositions like *on*, *over*, etc.; seeing what their corresponding nouns are with [the output](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=Open%20on%20a%20small%20school%20classroom%20in%20south%20Italy&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=1) [of the parse](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=Cut%20to%20dawn%20breaking%20over%20a%20wheat%20field&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=1), and checking whether those nouns are [a location](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=1&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=1&o5=1&o9=&o6=1&o3=1&o4=1&r=1&s=field&i=2&h=10000000000000000000000#c) or maybe are [hyponyms of something like a structure](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=1&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=1&o5=1&o9=&o6=1&o3=1&o4=1&r=1&s=schoolroom&i=5&h=11000100#c) or something similar using wordnet.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks